# error setting transparency in CSS file

Tags: css

I am trying to set the transparency of a table background color. But when I write this code in CSS it shows me the error "Validation (CSS2.1): filter is not a known property name" 
and the same error for opacity.

Why is this so?

```
.semiTransparent 
{ 
 filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css filter is IE-specific. If you don't use color: rgba(r,g,b,a); where a is alpha channel responsible for transparency, you must use a few improper css properties to have semi-transparent object in all browsers.

```
.semiTransparent {
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Above code works in all browsers, but is invalid.

Comment: i tried this code but this code is not working in IE
but working only in mozilla

Comment: As a matter of fact, filter property setting is considered ActiveX, so you must have them turned on or asked for. It works in other browsers without problems (opera, firefox, chrome, safari).

Answer (score 2):

> The CSS Validator validates your style sheet against some profile, e.g. CSS Level 1 or CSS Level 2. Some browser Vendors however extend these profiles by new properties like Microsoft did with the scrollbar-base-color or filter  property or Mozilla with the -moz-opacity  property. The Validator is not aware of these properties and using them makes your style sheet invalid in terms of the CSS specifications. Either get rid of those properties or live with the fact, that your style sheets don't validate. You cannot have both.

http://www.websitedev.de/css/validator-faq :-)

Answer (score 1):

filter is technically not a standard compliant property, it only works for IE.  The opacity should be 0.5 not .5.  Minor changes.

Comment: I am using IE 7 but still transparency effect is not reflecting.
Moreover error is still persistant in CSS file

Comment: yup
it works in mozilla but doesn't works with IE
what can be done to resolve this problem